# How to set @PostMapping and @DeleteMapping to one URL Mapping? (without @RequestMapping)

Tags: java, spring-boot, web, spring-restcontroller

My English is not good, so some sentences maybe make you feel confused. Sorry about this.

I need a URL Mapping support those two request:

```
POST   http://localhost:8080/sth/delete
DELETE http://localhost:8080/sth
```

I cannot use `@RequestMapping({"/sth", "/sth/delete"})`, because there's duplicate url method. Is there any good way to fix this?

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping("/sth/delete")
    @DeleteMapping("/sth")     // this mapping not work
    public String deleteSth(){
        return "delete success";
    }

}
```

My solution is write two void , and one use @PostMapping, another use @DeleteMapping, and return the same value. If follow this, will make all url mapping copy.

Answer (score 2):

Normaly, you can't add two XxxMapping on same method, it's spring mvc limit, you can take a look at the spring source code:

`RequestMappingHandlerMapping.createRequestMappingInfo(AnnotatedElement element)`

it's get single RequestMapping annotation from your controller's method.

So you can define two method, one use @PostMapping, another use @DeleteMapping

or you need rewrite spring bean to get all annotation define.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to find solution out of 'code side'. Maybe change the product requirements ：）